# Excel Using a cel reference to build a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of data with a large number of sumifs statements.  The problem is that the total length of the table is different every month.  I have a cell reference (B18) with the number of rows in the current table.  Is there a way to reference the number in cell B18 so that when the number of rows changes next month, the formula still works?  See the sumifs statement below:  Please note that I hope to replace all 1862 with this reference to the number in B18.

=SUM(SUMIFS("$G$20:$G$"&[reference to the number in B18],$H$20:$H$1862,C4,$B$20:$B$1862,{"TUADJ","TUIT"}))

Thanks so much for any help.

Larry Toone

Comment: Is anything stopping you from referring to the table, or table column, rather than specific cells?

Comment: Christofer Weber's solution does what you want, but might I suggest adding your data to a table, and changing your formula to use "structured cell references"?  assuming your table always has the same headers, so it won't matter if the length is different.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e  http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/structured-references.html

Answer (score 0):

To insert a reference to a number (or any value/content in a cell) you can use the `=INDIRECT` function.

In your case, this could look like

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("G20:G"&$B$18),$H$20:$H$1862,C4,$B$20:$B$1862,{"TUADJ","TUIT"}))
```

Or to change them all:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("G20:G"&$B$18),INDIRECT("H20:H"&$B$18),C4,INDIRECT("B20:B"&$B$18),{"TUADJ","TUIT"}))
```